# Request-URI Too Large error came [while encoding image using base64 and send to php]

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

1. Encoding:

   ```
    NSData *imageData2 =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image_emp.image, 0.1);
   [Base64 initialize];
    NSString *encodedString = [imageData2 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
   ```

   1. json:

      ```
      NSString *posturl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxx.com/image.php?img=%@",encodedString];
      //[posturl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];


        NSString* urlTextEscaped = [posturl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSLog(@"replace log %@",urlTextEscaped);

       [urlTextEscaped stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];

       NSLog(@"the office login url is %@",posturl);
       NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urlTextEscaped]];

       //  NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[posturl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

       NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
       [request setURL:url];


        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSError *error;
        NSURLResponse *response;

        NSData *urldata=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urldata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"the overall value is %@",data);


         NSDictionary *results=[data JSONValue];
          NSLog(@"the results:%@",results);
         NSArray *value=[results objectForKey:@"message"];
           NSLog(@"the array value %@",value);
      ```
   2. array value[log]:

      ```
           Request-URI Too Large
      ```

How can I solve this type of issue.Kindly give any ideas.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: not related to your problem, general advice for you: You should never call `+ initialize` manually. It is invoked automatically when you use the class for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't POST the data in the URL, take advantage of the post body and submit it there. It's the only way to get a lengthy amount of data submitted.